# Ministry of Knowledge Economy of South Korea

Tags: economy, government, terminology

South Korea had a ministry called [Ministry of Knowledge Economy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Trade,_Industry_and_Energy)

In 1948, it was Ministry of Commerce in the First Republic of South Korea. In 1993 it was merged with the Ministry of Energy, established in 1977. 
It became the ***Ministry of Knowledge Economy in 2008***, and the Ministry of Trade, Industry and Energy just recently in 2013.

So,

1. What was the objective behind using the word "Knowledge"?
2. How the "Ministry of Knowledge Economy" was different, if it was, from [G8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G8) economies' economy or commerce ministries?
3. What are the reasons for changing from "Ministry of Knowledge Economy" to "Ministry of Trade, Industry and Energy" in 2013?

Answer (score 5):

To answer #1, the "knowledge" is similar to the term "informational" in English phrase.

This is a term coming from naming the stages of economic development, with the latter stage being "[Informational Economy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_economy)" (aka "[Knowledge Economy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_economy)"), in a sense of being post-industrial economy; where the foundation of the economic productivity is knowledge/information and not agriculture or industrial labor as the preceding models.

Comment: I won't be able to answer #2 since too many countries have varied "commerce" type ministries. Please narrow it down to specific country so proper can be made.